# Plotting Vertical Bars with Different Origins

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot data representing some soil samples below the ground.

In some points (Horizontal Place) I have just one sample, and in other ones I have two samples, one below other (Vertical Sample A and B).

The difference between Vertical Samples in place where there are 2 samples is the size of the sample, so I could plot it as a histogram but the origin from the samples are not the same neither equal to zero, so histogram and barchart do not works well.

I'm trying to plot something similar to this [image]

I took a look at matplotlib and do not found something similar to it.

Please can you advise me what could be the best plot to use on it ?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Horizontal_Place' : [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], 'Vertical_Sample' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A','B'], 
              'Depth_Top' : [-1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -3], 'Depth_Bottom' : [-2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4]})
```

Comment: That looks like a simple line plot with [annotations](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html). Unfortunately, without knowing what code you've tried so far, we can't really help you more. Please post code once you've tried some things.

Comment: @G.Anderson is not a simple line with annotation, forgot the green and blue line. My problem is to put all the samples with the right size in the right place (vertical and horizontal)...the green and blue lines are other series....

Comment: It looks like one figure with the green line as one line plot, the blue line as another line plot, and it _looks_ like a bunch of stacked annotations at each data point on the green line. I apologize if I'm misunderstanding, but the answer remains the same: You can definitely do this in matplotlib, but this forum exists to help with specific questions when you get stuck, general "Can I" or "How can I" questions are considered too broad or off-topic

Comment: ok @G.Anderson, sorry, I understood your point! it's because I am really starting with python...but...I think I can do it with broken_barh method....I will try and asap I post the result...cheers

Comment: Good luck! If you get stuck, feel free to ask lots more questions once you have something specific!

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks, I got it but now I'm stucked in another step of the code that I have posted in another question in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749012/python-typeerror-1-is-not-a-string