# Python - TypeError: 1 is not a string -

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to execute the code below but for some reason it raises the error "TypeError: 1 is not a string".

I don't understand why because when I run it changing the dataset to a simple list with integers it's work.

I'm importing the dataset in pandas in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

data = pd.read_csv('sedimento.csv', encoding ='latin-1', delimiter=';', decimal=',')
```

The importing is working well and the resulting dataset is something like that:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"xmin": [1, 1, 2], "ymin": [-13.2, -14.2, -12.76], "ymax": [-12.2, -13.2, -11.76]})
```

So I define the parameters to make a plot in a map and lambda function:

```
xw = 1
xmin = data['xmin']
ymin = data['ymin']
ymax = data['ymax']

plt.figure()
list(map(lambda x,y,z:plt.broken_barh([(x,xw)], (y, z), facecolors = 'blue'), xmin,ymin,ymax))
```

So the "TypeError: 1 is not a string" rises right here!

Comment: Your code works fine for me producing a plot

Comment: @Bazingaa yes I have tested it so the data as I put here is working well, but when I try to run directly from the file that I've imported it doesn't work. I think can be some problem with the importing

Comment: You will have to look more carefully in the contents of the file OR the dataframe generated after reading from the file

Comment: Yes I will do it! Thanks and sorry for wasting time